# The usage of "run a mile" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, idioms, expressions, phrases

The phrase ["run a mile"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run-a-mile) means:

> To try to avoid a situation or a person because you are embarrassed or frightened.

Based on this definition, I wonder if you could let me know whether the following sentence sounds natural and the usage of this verb is correct:

> He's completely against marriage. He runs a mile "**from**" girls when it comes to marriage.

I have visited many web pages which had lots of examples including the phrase, but never found a preposition "from" in even one sentences to be used along with this phrase. It was why I made up a sentence and brought it up in the forum.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94063/discussion-on-question-by-a-friend-the-usage-of-run-a-mile-in-a-sentence).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was surprised to see comments from native speakers unfamiliar with the expression (*very* well-known to me). But apparently this is primarily a ***British English*** colloquial usage...

[image]

---

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-a-mile)...

> ***run a mile***  (UK informal)
>    to be extremely unwilling to be involved:
>    *He'd run a mile if I asked him to marry me.*

As it happens, the above example doesn't include a ***from*** clause, but there's no reason why it couldn't. The speaker there might just as well have said...

> *He'd run a mile **from any girl** who asked him to marry her.*

We also say we'll ***give a wide berth to*** [something we really want to avoid], which often amounts to the same thing (essentially, avoiding something either by running far away from it, or by making sure you don't go anywhere near it in the first place).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers. But what phrase should I use to make sense to all natives as it's not understood to a majority of them? :-?

Comment: I think "He'd *run away* from any girl..." or "He'd *flee* from any girl..." could also work. "run away" and "flee" can be used figuratively to mean "avoid".

Comment: @Mixolydian: In most such contexts, ***flee*** would be a hopelessly outdated / fancy / poetic term to use today.

Comment: @A-friend: I was too polite to explicitly mention it in my actual answer, but the intended meaning would always be so contextually obvious I'd expect any native speaker to understand and accept it without thinking it was somehow "unusual" or "opaque", even on first encounter. You don't *need* to include ***a mile***, which is just an obviously-available "intensifier" here anyway, so *He'd run [away] from any girl who asked him to marry her* would get the point across just as well.

Comment: I, too, was unfamiliar with *run a mile* — 1.62 km isn't exactly far, after all — and the phrase would be more comprehensible just to say *run [away] from*, or perhaps *make a run from* to emphasize urgency. I agree *flee* alone is mostly literary, but he might *flee the scene*, short for *flee the scene of the crime*, for beating a hasty exit, or *keep his distance from* such girls if expressing strategic caution.

Comment: Alternatively, we Americans might just be too fat these days to comprehend running a mile from anything.

Comment: Well @Mixolydian, diesn't the verb "flee" sound a bit archaic in this sense? As we've already diacussed about it in my previous threads. :-?

Comment: @A-friend not sure what previous threads you mean. But yes, I guess *flee* is not very common in modern spoken English, as other commenters point out. It could have a humorous effect in this context.

Comment: @Mixolydian: As I recall, some early comments under the question appeared to be from (AmE) native speakers who didn't recognise the expression - mostly now deleted, and the rest moved to chat. I suppose it's feasible a native speaker might use (mock-archaic?) ***flee*** "facetiously", but I certainly wouldn't recommend non-native speakers trying to follow suit. You normally need to have a ***very*** good ear for (your own) language to be able to successfully "play" with it like that; most learners will never get anywhere near that level in a foreign language.